# WooCommerce product with custom select fields and price calculation issue

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I am working on a Woocommerce Plugin I  am trying to make the customization on Product page but the value isn't getting changed on the page and when I do add to cart it takes both the value i.e the value of product already in there and the price of product after customization.
As the add to cart works perfectly but I am only facing the issue while adding custome price after product customization.

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'add_to_cart_product_pricing',);
function add_to_cart_product_pricing()
{
    global $woocommerce, $product, $wpdb;

    if (is_a($woocommerce, 'WooCommerce') && is_product()) {

        // Targeting "ring" or "rings" product category
        if (has_term(array('ring', 'rings'), 'product_cat')) {

            // Load the latest gold rate
            $gold_rate_table = $wpdb->prefix . 'gold_rate';
            $gold_rate = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT final_price FROM $gold_rate_table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");

            //Get Metal Purity
            $metal_purity = $product->get_attribute('metal-purity');
            $metal_purity_table = $wpdb->prefix . 'diamond_purity';

            // Prepare the SQL query with proper escaping
            $query = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT percentage FROM $metal_purity_table WHERE purity = %s", $metal_purity);

            // Run the prepared query
            $metalpurity = $wpdb->get_var($query);

            $goldvalue = ($gold_rate * $metalpurity) / 100;

            // Diamond Shape
            $dquality = $product->get_attribute('diamond-quality');
            $sieves = $product->get_attribute('sieves');
            $dweight = $product->get_attribute('diamond-weight-ct');
            $dpieces = $product->get_attribute('diamond-pieces');


            $round_diamond_table = $wpdb->prefix . 'round_diamond';

            // Prepare the SQL query with proper escaping
            $query = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT $sieves FROM $round_diamond_table WHERE diamond_quality = %s", $dquality);

            // Run the prepared query
            $dshape = $wpdb->get_var($query);

            $dtotal = ($dshape * ($dweight / 5));
            $dmtotal = $dtotal * $dpieces;



            // Get net weight product attribute
            $net_weight = $product->get_attribute('net-weight-g');

            // Get product regular price
            $regular_price = $product->get_regular_price();

            // Calculate product updated price
            $updated_price = ($goldvalue * $net_weight) + $regular_price + $dmtotal;

            // Get the displayed price 
            $args = array('price' => floatval($updated_price));

            if ('incl' === get_option('woocommerce_tax_display_shop')) {
                $displayed_price = wc_get_price_including_tax($product, $args);
            } else {
                $displayed_price = wc_get_price_excluding_tax($product, $args);
            }


            // Display product updated price
            printf('<p class="productprice">%s</p>', wc_price($displayed_price));

            // Display a hidden input field with the "updated_price" as value
            printf('<input type="hidden" name="updated_price" value="%s" />', $updated_price);

            // Get gross weight product attribute 
            $gross_weight = $product->get_attribute('gross-weight');

            // Display the Gross Weight
            printf('<p class="grossweight">' . __('Weight: %s g') . '</p>', $gross_weight);
            // Store the updated price in a global variable
            global $updated_price;
        }
        
    }
}

add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'customization_of_product', 32);
function customization_of_product()
{
    global $product, $wpdb;
    if (has_term(array('ring', 'rings'), 'product_cat')) {
        echo '<div class="customization-form">
        <form id="customization-form" method="POST">
            <label for="ring-size">Ring Size:</label>';
            
    // Ring Size
    $ring_size_table = $wpdb->prefix . 'ring_size';
    $results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $ring_size_table");
    echo '<select name="ring-size" id="ring-size">
                <option value="">Ring Sizes</option>';
    foreach ($results as $result) {
        echo '<option value="' . $result->ring_size . '">' . $result->ring_size . '</option>';
    }
    echo '</select><br> <label for="metal-purity">Metal Purity:</label>';
    
    // Metal Purity
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'diamond_purity';
    $results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $table_name WHERE purity='14kt' OR purity='18kt'");
    echo '<select name="metal-purity" id="metal-purity">
                <option value="">Metal Purity</option>';
    foreach ($results as $result) {
        echo '<option value="' . $result->purity . '">' . $result->purity . '</option>';
    }
    echo '</select>';
    
    echo '<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
    </div>';

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        // Get the submitted values
        $ring_size = $_POST['ring-size'];
        $metal_purity = $_POST['metal-purity'];

        // Calculate the updated price
        $updated_price = calculate_updated_price($product, $ring_size, $metal_purity);

         // Remove any existing items of the same product from the cart
         foreach (WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item) {
            if ($cart_item['product_id'] === $product->get_id()) {
                WC()->cart->remove_cart_item($cart_item_key);
            }
        }
        // Set the updated price in the cart item data
        $cart_item_data = array(
            'updated_price' => $updated_price,
            'unique_key' => md5(microtime() . rand())
        );

        // Add the cart item
        WC()->cart->add_to_cart($product->get_id(), 1, 0, array(), $cart_item_data);

        // Get the updated cart value
        $updated_cart_value = WC()->cart->get_cart_total();

        // Display the updated cart value
        echo 'Updated Cart Value: ' . $updated_cart_value;
    }
    }

   
}
// Function to calculate the updated price
function calculate_updated_price($product, $ring_size, $metal_purity)
{
    global $wpdb;


    // Load the latest gold rate
    $gold_rate_table = $wpdb->prefix . 'gold_rate';
    $gold_rate = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT final_price FROM $gold_rate_table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");

    // Get Metal Purity percentage
    $metal_purity_table = $wpdb->prefix . 'diamond_purity';
    $query = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT percentage FROM $metal_purity_table WHERE purity = %s", $metal_purity);
    $metal_purity_percentage = $wpdb->get_var($query);


    // Calculate gold value
    $gold_value = ($gold_rate * $metal_purity_percentage) / 100;
    

    // Get net weight product attribute
    $net_weight = $product->get_attribute('net-weight-g');

    // Get size gram variation
    $ring_size_table = $wpdb->prefix . 'ring_size';
    $query = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT variation_grams FROM $ring_size_table WHERE ring_size = %s", $ring_size);
    $ring_grams_percentage = $wpdb->get_var($query);

    // Get product regular price
    $regular_price = $product->get_regular_price();
    // Diamond Shape
    $dquality = $product->get_attribute('diamond-quality');
    $sieves = $product->get_attribute('sieves');
    $dweight = $product->get_attribute('diamond-weight-ct');
    $dpieces = $product->get_attribute('diamond-pieces');


    $round_diamond_table = $wpdb->prefix . 'round_diamond';

    // Prepare the SQL query with proper escaping
    $query = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT $sieves FROM $round_diamond_table WHERE diamond_quality = %s", $dquality);

    // Run the prepared query
    $dshape = $wpdb->get_var($query);

    $dtotal = ($dshape * ($dweight / 5));
    $dmtotal = $dtotal * $dpieces;



    $default_ring_size = $product->get_attribute('default-ring-size');
    if ($default_ring_size < $ring_size) {
        $netweight = $net_weight + $ring_grams_percentage;
       

        // Calculate product updated pric
        $updated_price = ($gold_value * $netweight) + $regular_price + $dmtotal;
    } elseif ($default_ring_size = $ring_size) {

        $updated_price = ($gold_value * $net_weight) + $regular_price + $dmtotal;
    } else {
        $netweight2 = $net_weight - $ring_grams_percentage;
        
        $updated_price = ($gold_value * $netweight2) + $regular_price + $dmtotal;
    }



    // Get the displayed price 
    $args = array('price' => floatval($updated_price));

    if ('incl' === get_option('woocommerce_tax_display_shop')) {
        $displayed_price = wc_get_price_including_tax($product, $args);
    } else {
        $displayed_price = wc_get_price_excluding_tax($product, $args);
    }


    // Display product updated price
    printf('<p class="productprice">%s</p>', wc_price($displayed_price));

    // Display a hidden input field with the "updated_price" as value
    printf('<input type="hidden" name="updated_price" value="%s" />', $updated_price);

    return $updated_price;
}


add_filter('woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'save_custom_cart_item_data', 10, 2);
function save_custom_cart_item_data($cart_item_data, $product_id)
{

    if (isset($_POST['updated_price']) && !empty($_POST['updated_price'])) {
        // Set the custom data in the cart item
        $cart_item_data['updated_price'] = (float) wc_clean($_POST['updated_price']);

        // Make each item as a unique separated cart item
        $cart_item_data['unique_key'] = md5(microtime() . rand());
    }
    return $cart_item_data;
}

add_action('woocommerce_cart_item_price', 'filter_cart_displayed_price', 10, 2);
function filter_cart_displayed_price($price, $cart_item)
{
    if (isset($cart_item['updated_price'])) {
        $args = array('price' => floatval($cart_item['updated_price']));

        if ('incl' === get_option('woocommerce_tax_display_cart')) {
            $product_price = wc_get_price_including_tax($cart_item['data'], $args);
        } else {
            $product_price = wc_get_price_excluding_tax($cart_item['data'], $args);
        }
        return wc_price($product_price);
    }
    return $price;
}
add_action('woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'set_new_cart_item_updated_price');
function set_new_cart_item_updated_price($cart)
{
    if ((is_admin() && !defined('DOING_AJAX')))
        return;

    if (did_action('woocommerce_before_calculate_totals') >= 2)
        return;

    // Loop through cart items and set the updated price
    foreach ($cart->get_cart() as $cart_item) {
        // Set the new price
        if (isset($cart_item['updated_price'])) {
            $cart_item['data']->set_price($cart_item['updated_price']);
        }
    }
}
```

I Tried doing:

```
    // Calculate the updated price
    $updated_price = calculate_updated_price($product, $ring_size, $metal_purity);

     // Remove any existing items of the same product from the cart
     foreach (WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item) {
        if ($cart_item['product_id'] === $product->get_id()) {
            WC()->cart->remove_cart_item($cart_item_key);
        }
    }`
```

But it takes both the values the initial one and the customized one.

Comment: There is a mistake in your code for a table name, here `// Metal Purity
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'diamond_purity';`, it should be like `'metal_purity'` instead, don't you think?

Comment: Hey, as I already had that table so I am working with 'diamond_purity' We'll be changing it asap in production!

Comment: Hey, I have emailed you! thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This requires jQuery and Ajax, to get it working as you expect.

I have revisited all your code, separating all custom SQL queries in individual functions, that are now reusable.

All the product data (product attributes, price and the gold rate) are now in a separated (reusable) function:

I have removed your submit button (and the custom form), moved the 2 selectors inside the Add to cart form, so they are displayed just before the add to cart button (inside the add to cart form). On start, the default values (from the product) are set on each select field (which was not the case before), so there is no need of validation as there will be always selected values.

Now, when the customer selects something else, the price is calculated and updated automatically via Ajax. During the Ajax process (2 seconds), everything is blocked on the form (just like in checkout Ajax events).

I have tricked your custom sql queries with fake values, to check that everything works. Same thing for the. product attributes.

Here is that revisited code:

Jquery (Ajax) external file named "price-calculator.js"

```js
jQuery( function($){
    if (typeof wc_add_to_cart_params === 'undefined')
        return false;

    var ringSize     = $('select#ring-size').val(),
        metalPurity  = $('select#metal-purity').val(),
        productId    = $('button[name=add-to-cart]').val();

    function sendSelectedData( ringSize, metalPurity, productId ) {
        $('form.cart').block({message: null, overlayCSS: {background: '#fff', opacity: 0.6}});
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: wc_add_to_cart_params.ajax_url,
            data: {
                'action':        'updating_price',
                'product_id':    productId,
                'ring_size':     ringSize,
                'metal_purity':  metalPurity 
            },
            success: function (res) {
                var response = $.parseJSON(res);
                $('input#updated_price').val(response['raw']);
                $('p.product-price').html(response['html']);
                $('form.cart').unblock();

                 console.log(response); // just for testing | TO BE REMOVED
            },
            error: function (err) {
                $('form.cart').unblock();

                 console.log(err); // just for testing | TO BE REMOVED
            }
        });
    }

    $('form.cart').on('change', 'select#ring-size', function(){
        ringSize = $(this).val();
        sendSelectedData( ringSize, metalPurity, productId );
    });

    $('form.cart').on('change', 'select#metal-purity', function(){
        metalPurity = $(this).val();
        sendSelectedData( ringSize, metalPurity, productId );
    });
});
```

The PHP part:

```php
// Make sure WooCommerce is active
if ( ! in_array( 'woocommerce/woocommerce.php', apply_filters( 'active_plugins', get_option( 'active_plugins' ) ) ) ) {
    return;
}

// Register main jQuery script (for a wp plugin)
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_ajax_price_calculation_js' );
function add_ajax_price_calculation_js() {
    // Only on front-end and checkout page
    if( ! is_admin() || ( is_checkout() && ! is_wc_endpoint_url() ) ) {
        // Load the datepicker jQuery-ui plugin script
        wp_enqueue_script( 'ajax-price-calculator',  plugins_url( 'assets/js/price-calculator.js', __FILE__ ), array('jquery'), false, true );
    }

}

// Utility function to get the gold rate from the database
function get_gold_rate() {
    global $wpdb;
    return $wpdb->get_var("SELECT final_price FROM {$wpdb->prefix}gold_rate ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");
}

// Utility function to get the metal purity from the database
function get_metal_purity($metal_purity) {
    global $wpdb;
    return (float) $wpdb->get_var(
        $wpdb->prepare("
        SELECT percentage FROM {$wpdb->prefix}diamond_purity 
        WHERE purity = %s", $metal_purity)
    );
}

// Utility function to get the diamond shape from the database
function get_diamond_shape($diamond_sieves, $diamond_quality) {
    global $wpdb;
    return (float) $wpdb->get_var(
        $wpdb->prepare("
        SELECT {$diamond_sieves} FROM {$wpdb->prefix}round_diamond 
        WHERE diamond_quality = '%s'", $diamond_quality)
    );
}

// Utility function to get the ring sizes from the database
function get_ring_sizes() {
    global $wpdb;
    return $wpdb->get_col("SELECT ring_size FROM {$wpdb->prefix}ring_size");
}

// Utility function to get the metal purity from the database
function get_metal_purity_14k_18k() {
    global $wpdb;
    return $wpdb->get_col("SELECT purity FROM {$wpdb->prefix}diamond_purity
    WHERE purity IN ('14kt','18kt')");
}

// Utility function to get the ring grams % from the database
function get_ring_grams_percentage($ring_size) {
    global $wpdb;
    return $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare("
        SELECT variation_grams FROM {$wpdb->prefix}ring_size WHERE ring_size = %s", $ring_size));
}

// Utility function to get and format the updated price for display
function get_displayed_price_html($price, $product) {
    $args = array('price' => floatval($price));

    if ('incl' === get_option('woocommerce_tax_display_shop')) {
        return wc_price(wc_get_price_including_tax($product, $args));
    } else {
        return wc_price(wc_get_price_excluding_tax($product, $args));
    }
}

// Utility function to get all required product data (including gold rate)
function get_all_product_data($product, $all = false) {
    $data1 = array('metal_purity' => $product->get_attribute('metal-purity')); // Not for calculation
    $data2 = array(
        'diamond_quality' => $product->get_attribute('diamond-quality'),
        'diamond_sieves'  => $product->get_attribute('sieves'),
        'diamond_weight'  => $product->get_attribute('diamond-weight-ct'),
        'diamond_pieces'  => $product->get_attribute('diamond-pieces'),
        'net_weight'      => $product->get_attribute('net-weight-g'),
        'dft_ring_size'   => $product->get_attribute('default-ring-size'),
        'gross_weight'    => $product->get_attribute('gross-weight'),
        'regular_price'   => $product->get_regular_price(), // Regular price
        'gold_rate'       => get_gold_rate(), // Load the latest gold rate
    );
    return $all ? array_merge($data1, $data2) : $data2;
}

// Remove Woocommerce displayed price
add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'hide_regular_price_show_updated_price', 1);
function hide_regular_price_show_updated_price() {
    if ( has_term( array('ring', 'rings'), 'product_cat' ) ) {
        remove_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price', 10);
    }
}

// Add some custom form fields to single product add to cart form
add_action('woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'add_to_cart_product_pricing',);
function add_to_cart_product_pricing() {
    global $product;

    // Targeting "ring" or "rings" product category
    if ( is_product()&& has_term(array('ring', 'rings'), 'product_cat') ) {
        // Get necessary product data, converting each element to usable variables (incl gold rate)
        extract(get_all_product_data($product, true));

        // Load data from custom tables for further calculations
        $metal_purity_percent  = get_metal_purity($metal_purity); // Metal Purity percent
        $diamond_shape = get_diamond_shape($diamond_sieves, $diamond_quality); // Get the diamond shape

        // Calculations
        $gold_value    = ($gold_rate * $metal_purity_percent) / 100; // Gold value
        $diamond_total = ($diamond_shape * ($diamond_weight / 5)) * $diamond_pieces; // diamond total
        $calc_price    = round( ($gold_value * $net_weight) + $regular_price + $diamond_total ); // Calculated price

        // Displaying product calculated price and Gross Weight
        printf('<p class="product-price">%s</p>', get_displayed_price_html($calc_price, $product));
        printf('<p class="grossweight">' . __('Weight: %s') . '</p>', wc_format_weight($gross_weight)); 

        echo '<div class="custom-fields">';

        echo '<label for="ring-size">' . __("Ring Size") . ':</label>
        <select id="ring-size" name="ring_size">';

        // Loop through ring sizes
        foreach (get_ring_sizes() as $ring_size) {
            printf( '<option value="%s"%s>%s</option>',$ring_size, selected($ring_size, $def_ring_size), $ring_size );
        }
        echo '</select><br>';

        echo ' <label for="metal-purity">' . __("Metal Purity") . ':</label>
        <select id="metal-purity" name="metal_purity">';

        // Loop through metal purity       
        foreach (get_metal_purity_14k_18k() as $purity) {
            printf( '<option value="%s"%s>%s</option>', $purity, selected($purity, $metal_purity), $purity );
        }
        echo '</select>
        <input type="hidden" id="updated_price" name="updated_price" value="'.$calc_price.'" />
        </div>';
    }
}

// PHP Ajax receiver
add_action( 'wp_ajax_updating_price', 'calculating_price_update' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_updating_price', 'calculating_price_update' );
function calculating_price_update() {
    if ( isset($_POST['product_id']) && isset($_POST['ring_size']) && isset($_POST['metal_purity']) ) {
        $product = wc_get_product( intval($_POST['product_id']) ); // get the Product object

        // Get necessary product data, converting each element to usable variables (incl gold rate)
        extract(get_all_product_data($product));

        $ring_size    = esc_attr($_POST['ring_size']); // Get selected "ring size"
        $metal_purity = esc_attr($_POST['metal_purity']);// Get selected "metal purity"

        // Load data from custom tables for further calculations
        $metal_purity_percent = get_metal_purity($metal_purity); // Metal Purity percentage
        $ring_grams_percent   = get_ring_grams_percentage($ring_size); // size gram variation
        $diamond_shape        = get_diamond_shape($diamond_sieves, $diamond_quality); // diamond shape

        // Pre calculations
        $gold_value    = ($gold_rate * $metal_purity_percent) / 100;  // Calculate gold value
        $diamond_total = ($diamond_shape * ($diamond_weight / 5)) * $diamond_pieces;

        // Get calculated updated price
        if ($def_ring_size < $ring_size) {
            $net_weight_1  = $net_weight + $ring_grams_percent;
            $updated_price = ($gold_value * $net_weight_1) + $regular_price + $diamond_total;
        } elseif ($def_ring_size == $ring_size) {
            $updated_price = ($gold_value * $net_weight) + $regular_price + $diamond_total;
        } else {
            $net_weight_2  = $net_weight - $ring_grams_percent;
            $updated_price = round( ($gold_value * $net_weight_2) + $regular_price + $diamond_total );
        }
        // Send back the updated price data to jQuery
        echo json_encode( array(
            'raw' => $updated_price, 
            'html' => get_displayed_price_html($updated_price, $product) 
        ) );
    }
    wp_die(); // Always Exit silently
}

// Add custom cart item data
add_filter('woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'save_custom_cart_item_data', 10, 2);
function save_custom_cart_item_data($cart_item_data, $product_id) {
    if ( isset($_POST['updated_price']) && ! empty($_POST['updated_price']) ) {
        $cart_item_data['updated_price'] = (float) esc_html($_POST['updated_price']); // Custom calculated price

        if ( isset($_POST['ring_size']) && ! empty($_POST['ring_size']) ) {
            $cart_item_data['ring_size'] = esc_attr($_POST['ring_size']); // Ring size
        }

        if ( isset($_POST['metal_purity']) && ! empty($_POST['metal_purity']) ) {
            $cart_item_data['metal_purity'] = esc_attr($_POST['metal_purity']); // Metal purity
        }
        // Make each item as a unique separated cart item
        $cart_item_data['unique_key'] = md5(microtime() . rand());
    }
    
    return $cart_item_data;
}

// Display cart item calculated price in Mini Cart
add_action('woocommerce_cart_item_price', 'filter_cart_displayed_price', 10, 2);
function filter_cart_displayed_price($price, $cart_item) {
    if ( has_term( array('ring', 'rings'), 'product_cat', $cart_item['product_id'] ) 
    && isset($cart_item['updated_price']) ) {
        $args = array('price' => floatval($cart_item['updated_price']));

        if ('incl' === get_option('woocommerce_tax_display_cart')) {
            $product_price = wc_get_price_including_tax($cart_item['data'], $args);
        } else {
            $product_price = wc_get_price_excluding_tax($cart_item['data'], $args);
        }
        return wc_price($product_price);
    }
    return $price;
}

// Set the calculated price in cart and checkout
add_action('woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'set_new_cart_item_updated_price');
function set_new_cart_item_updated_price($cart) {
    if ((is_admin() && !defined('DOING_AJAX')))
        return;

    if (did_action('woocommerce_before_calculate_totals') >= 2)
        return;

    // Loop through cart items and set the updated price
    foreach ($cart->get_cart() as $cart_item) {
        // Set the new price
        if (isset($cart_item['updated_price'])) {
            $cart_item['data']->set_price($cart_item['updated_price']);
        }
    }
}

// Save custom field values as order item metadata and display on orders
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item', 'save_custom_fields_as_order_item_metadata', 10, 4 );
function save_custom_fields_as_order_item_metadata( $item, $cart_item_key, $values, $order ) {
    if( array_key_exists('ring_size', $values) && array_key_exists('metal_purity', $values) ) {
        $item->add_meta_data('ring_size', $values['ring_size']);
        $item->add_meta_data('metal_purity', $values['metal_purity']);
    }
}

// Have a readable "meta key" label name replacementÒÒ
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_item_display_meta_key', 'filter_order_item_display_meta_key', 10, 3 );
function filter_order_item_display_meta_key( $display_key, $meta, $item ) {
    // only on Admin
    if ( $display_key === 'ring_size' ) {
        $display_key = __('Ring size');
    } elseif ( $display_key === 'metal_purity' ) {
        $display_key = __('Metal purity');
    }
    return $display_key;
}
```

The code can be used in:

- The functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme)
- In plugin.

It should work.

Comment: Hey, Thank you for the help, Just have one question I studied the code and try to add one more dropdown as dimaond_quality but in ajax its not able to calculate it. I have added the require code in js file as well but when I  put the && isset($_POST['diamond_quality']) in ajax receiver the calculation stops.